# Vue js( utilizar condicilnal dentro de for each)

Tags: vue.js

Quisiera saber cómo puedo utilizar un condicional dentro de un formato each con Vue js 
Por ejemplo de un arraay para seleccionar ciertos elementos dependiendo de un condicional

Comment: por favor lee [ask] agrega una muestra del código que tratas de filtrar y lo que has intentado

Comment: Bien shadow aún no lo tengo claro, solo intenté como tal tengo un vector en una variable de tipo vue, la cual llamo en un div con un v-for d in "personas" para asignar por ejemplo nombre, apellido uno debajo del otro pero lo quiero hacer es que válida si la persona tiene estado en 1 para que la muestre sino que la omita

Comment: Hola Christian! Podrías crear una propiedad computada que devuelva el array filtrado y luego recorrer esa propiedad en el template. [Displaying Filtered/Sorted Results](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results)